# tomcat json eclipse Java EE The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat8

I have a project android application, when I created WS class and by running the message that appears is: The requested resource is not available, I think my case is similar to the questions but does not satisfy my need. here is the

**code of my class WS:**

```
package testBiblio;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.PropertyResourceBundle;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

import java.sql.Statement;

@Path("/Bibbli")
public class biblioTestWS {

// Connection CONSTANTS
private static String LOGIN = null;
private static String PASSWORD = null;
private static String DRIVER = null;
public static Connection getConnection1() {
ResourceBundle rb = PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle("testBiblio.DBConf");
LOGIN = rb.getString("login");
PASSWORD = rb.getString("password");
DRIVER = rb.getString("driver");
URL = rb.getString("url");
Connection maConnection = null;
try {
Class.forName(DRIVER);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
System.out
println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
System.out.println("----------DRIVER CONNECTION");
e.printStackTrace();
System.out
println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
try {
maConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
} catch (SQLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
System.out
println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
System.out.println("----------DATA BASE ACCESS");
e.printStackTrace();
System.out
.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
return maConnection;
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/ville")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getVille(@QueryParam("City") String city_id) {

        Connection dbCon = null;
        dbCon = getConnection1();

        Statement stmt;
        try {
            stmt = dbCon.createStatement();

            String query = "SELECT lib_name FROM library where city_id = '"
                    + city_id + "';";

            System.out.println(query);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            System.out
            .println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out
            .println("------------------------- LISTE DES BIBLIO   ------------------");

            while (rs.next()) {

                String lib_name = rs.getString("lib_name");

                System.out
                .println("-------->>>>>> "+lib_name);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("library", lib_name);
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
    System.out
.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
return jsonArray.toString();
} catch (SQLException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
returnnull;
}

}
```

**code servlet**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LibraryServlet
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet ("/LibraryServlet")
public class LibraryServlet extends HttpServlet {


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Récuperation des informations

                String lib_name = request.getParameter("lib_name");
                String city_id = request.getParameter("city_id");


    }

}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>testBiblio</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ls</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>testBiblio.LibraryServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
      <param-value>/</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: And what is the resource you are trying to access when you get the error response?

Comment: I liked to connect data base Mysql